# mongodb сравнение полей

Tags: php, mongodb

есть два поля 'first' , 'second' ,не посоветуете как сравнить их в коллекции 'collection' . Чтобы выводило только те записи, где first не равняется second.  Mongodb 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({$where: function(){
   return obj.first !== obj.second} 
 })
```

Comment: $Query=$collection->find(array(
                'foreignKey' => new MongoId($foreignkey,
                'first'=>array(
                    '$exist'=>true
                ),
                '$where'=> function(){
                return 'first' !== 'second';}
            ));

Comment: В таком синтексисе под php как переделать?

Comment: я не в курсе. Это синтаксис для mongo-shell